# Why do I get a 'CSRF token missing or incorrect' error?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, python-3.x

I am trying to return a value from a View function in Django. That function is being called from a JavsScript code using Ajax, but I get thrown an error which reads 'Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect)'.

[JavaScript/Ajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERtCP.png)

[The Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFSAL.png)

The HTML code looks something like this:

```
    <div align="center" class="input-line">
     <form class="input-form" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type = "text" id = "ans" class = "form-control" name = "address" placeholder="Type postcode..."><br><br>
        <button id = "homeBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Find info</button><br><br>
     </form>
</div>
```

The View Function is:

```
    def result(request):
        if(request == 'POST'):
           param = request.form['my data']
           this = runAreaReview(param) #This returns a string
           return HttpResponse(this)
```

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on [Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), specifically the "Cookie-to-Header Token" method of protecting against it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**method 1**

For making post requests with ajax, you need to set a header called `HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN` and set it's value to a cookie which is stored in the browser by name `csrftoken`. [Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax). 
so in your ajax call, you should do something like this.

```
var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
 $.ajax(
     ...
     headers:{"HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN":csrftoken}
 );
```

also note that if you are using some reverse proxy server with something like nginx, make sure to froward this header as well to the django application.

**method 2**

you can disable csrf verification for this specific view by using an annotation. [Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt)

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def result(request):
    ...
```

**method 3**

**The method below is NOT RECOMMENDED for security reasons**

You can alwaws turnoff the csrf middleware in settings to get rid of it if you are just building something for recreational purpose and not for production.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I used the **csrf_exempt** and it doesn't throw that error anymore.
However now it throws an error saying the **View function did not return an Object. It returned None instead** 
I have linked my view function in the post itself, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: you should check with `request.method=="POST"`

Comment: also, I'd suggest using an IDE with debugger. It'll help you pinpoint the issue thus helps you fix it. :)

Answer (score 0):

for any one come across this thread, the HEADER key should be `X-CSRFToken` as for Django 2.1, links goes here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/